# CAS primaryAuthenticationHandler ldapAuthenticationHandler

Tags: configuration, active-directory, ldap, cas

I think I've exhausted searching and need to ask this seemingly very popular question about CAS configuration for Active Directory. I followed the steps on [CAS docs](http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.x/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html) to modify the deployerConfigContext.xml to include the `ldapAuthenticationHandler` bean.

But seems like CAS is continuing to use `AcceptUsersAuthenticationHandler` defined in the same file in the `primaryAuthenticationHandler` tag.

**Question**: So basically I need to replace `AcceptUsersAuthenticationHandler` with `ldapAuthenticationHandler` as the default authenticator. What is the correct syntax to do so in the following snippet?

```
<bean id="primaryAuthenticationHandler"
      class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AcceptUsersAuthenticationHandler">
    <property name="users">
        <map>
            <entry key="casuser" value="Mellon"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is what I have tried so far:

`<bean id="primaryAuthenticationHandler" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler"></bean>`
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler.`<init>`()**

`<bean id="primaryAuthenticationHandler" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.ldapAuthenticationHandler"></bean>`
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasig.cas.authentication.ldapAuthenticationHandler**

`<bean id="primaryAuthenticationHandler" class="ldapAuthenticationHandler"></bean>`
**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ldapAuthenticationHandler**

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the dependency in pom.xml?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId>
    <artifactId>cas-server-support-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>${cas.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, LdapAuthenticationHandler doesn't implement a default constructor, you need to configure a org.ldaptive.auth.Authenticator on the attribute c:authenticator-ref:

```
<bean id="ldapAuthenticationHandler"
  class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.LdapAuthenticationHandler"
  p:principalIdAttribute="mail"
  c:authenticator-ref="authenticator"/>
```

LDAP authentication is not as simple as the default hardcoded user/password authentication handler. In this link you can see an example on how to configure a connection to Active Directory: [Active Directory Authentication](https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.0.x/installation/LDAP-Authentication.html#active_directory_authentication)

Following the example, you will find in "LDAP Properties Starter" some properties defined. You will need to copy them to the file cas.properties on the same folder as deployerConfigContext.xml. You have to adjust the properties to your usecase and be aware that some of the properties names don't correspond with the ones on the xml examples.